# Ract native gl - Textures cannot read image assets in release build (Without metro server)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, opengl-es

When metro server is enabled Shader is applied to the child `image(uri:imgPath)`. But when debugger is disconnected from computer ,shader won't work.It just display empty background. Same issue in release build apk.

I assume the issue is in `{inputImageTexture2: require('../assets/filters/map.png')}` cannot get the image assets when metro server is disconnected. Without any external texture maps, shaders works without any issue even metro server is not running. Is there any other way to refer image assets. React native won't add those images into android apk's asset folder. I also manually put those images into asset folder. None of them worked. I identified react native compress those images and put them into android's resource folder.

```js
MyShader: {
        frag: `
      precision highp float;
      varying vec2 uv;

      uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
      uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;
     ..............
     ..............
```

```
export const Effect = ({children: inputImageTexture}) =>
    <Node
        shader={shaders.MyShader}
        uniforms={{
            inputImageTexture,
            inputImageTexture2: require('../assets/filters/map.png'),
        }}
    />;

<Surface style={{height: wp(100), width: wp(100)}} ref={image}>
        <Effect>
           {{uri:imgPath}}
       </Effect> 
</Surface>
```

Platform: Android 9.0
"react-native": "^0.62.0"